# Is an assumption a necessary or sufficient condition?

Tags: logic

In mathematics and logics, is an assumption for a statement/claim a necessary or sufficient condition for the statement/claim?

From my past experience with mathematics, an assumption may be neither. But in logical questions in GRE, GMAT and LSAT exams, an assumption seems to mean a necessary condition.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is a bit vague and it's quite possible the standardized test writers don't know any formal logic.  I hope the following discussion will clear things up.

*Claim:* Assume $P$. Then $Q$.

Here the meaning of the claim is precisely that the assumption $P$ is *sufficient* for the conclusion $Q$.  It may or may not be necessary.

However, note that there can be multiple assumptions:

*Claim:* Assume that $x$ is even and assume that $x$ is prime.  Then $x < 10$.

Here there are two assumptions, "$x$ is even" and "$x$ is prime", neither of which alone is necessary or sufficient for the conclusion $x < 10$.  However, note that the *conjunction* of the two assumptions is sufficient for the conclusion.  In general, if we package all of our assumptions into a single assumption (a conjunction of several sentences, perhaps) then this assumption is understood to be sufficient for the conclusion that follows.

---

EDIT: When working with sufficiently powerful theories, we very rarely know for certain that our assumptions are *necessary* for our conclusions, even if we think they are.  For example, if $\mathsf{ZFC}$ turned out to be inconsistent, then all of the assumptions anyone has ever made in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ theorems (beyond the $\mathsf{ZFC}$ axioms themselves, which are implicitly assumed) would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Assume Statement P.  To ask if Statement P is necessary or sufficient you need to specify "necessary or sufficient for what?"  For example: "Is Statement P a necessary or sufficient condition for Statement Q?"

If **something** follows from an assumption, then that assumption is a sufficient condition for that thing.  Example: Assume that $f(x)$ is differentiable.  It follows that $f$ is continuous.  Differentiablility is sufficient to make a function continuous, but certainly not necessary.  (For example, $g(x)=|x|$ is continuous but not differentiable.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% I understood, but here is my take:

An assumption may be necessary , sufficient, or necessary but not sufficient . It may, in some sense be neither , in a strictly causal sense connecting the two, but, if the conclusion is determined/given to be true, then the premise is at least sufficient.

Neither: If the claim is a tautology: claim :A=A  .Assumption: any thing you want.
OR there may be no connection between the two: I'm feeling hot, tomorrow is Friday.
EDIT: As pointed out by Wilson below, in some sense, in the material-conditional sense, any premise is sufficient, in that $P\rightarrow Q$ is considered to be true.

Necessary : (Assumption)  $x^2 >1$ , then (Claim) $|x|>1$ . The claim is also sufficient.

Necessary but not sufficient: if a number $n$ is prime, then $n$ is not divisible by $2$.
Not being even is necessary, but not all odd (i.e.,non-even) numbers are primes.

Sufficient but not necessary:  claim: $ x^2 =1$ , then (assumption) $x=1$ ; $x$ could be $-1$.

Comment: For your first example, if the conclusion is a tautology, then _any_ assumption is sufficient to prove it.  For your last example, it's a bit confusing to put the assumption at the end (after the "then".)

Comment: Right, that is what I meant; I was referring to the material conditional, in which there is no causal or other connection between the premise and the conclusion, other than just a truth-functional rule $ (F \rightarrow T):=T$  or $T \rightarrow T : T$. Yes; the assumptions do not always have an effect on the claim being made. This is also, of course true, in fallacies.

Comment: Assume that my cat likes pizza (this is the "anything I want".)  Claim: $A=A$.  Here the assumption is sufficient for the claim.  (It's not relevant, but as you said this is the material conditional and it has nothing to do with relevance.)  The reason I'm pointing this out is that the first example is labeled "neither", meaning "neither necessary nor sufficient".

Comment: Well, you have a point, but it may also be a matter of semantics. Maybe it is sufficient in this sense. I thought the question is somewhat open-ended. Still, let me edit that into the answer.

Comment: The question certainly is vague, but I think if there is only one assumption then that assumption should always be considered sufficient for the conclusion that follows.  It would be strange to consider tautological conclusions as a special case, especially because it may not be easy to figure out whether the conclusion is in fact tautological.

Comment: Ah, I had to run into a logician : ) . I did some editing above to reflect this point. I think it addresses your reservations.

Comment: It does, except that you still say "neither" at the beginning.  You might also note that in the second example the assumption is sufficient as well as necessary.

Comment: O.K, I reedited.